# Can't get specific index of $_POST

Tags: php

In my code I perform an ajax request and send this content:

```
Object {appointment_data: "{"id_services":["13","13"],"id_users_provider":"86…lable":false,"id":"133","id_users_customer":"87"}", customer_data: "{"first_name":"Mario","last_name":"Rossi","email":…:"","city":"","zip_code":"","notes":"","id":"87"}"}
appointment_data: "{"id_services":["13","13"],"id_users_provider":"86","start_datetime":"2015-11-19 13:43:00","end_datetime":"2015-11-19 14:55:00","notes":"","is_unavailable":false,"id":"133","id_users_customer":"87"}"
customer_data: "{"first_name":"Mario","last_name":"Rossi","email":"mrossi@net.it","phone_number":"0000","address":"","city":"","zip_code":"","notes":"","id":"87"}"
```

NB: this content is included in `appointment` variable that's json encode:

```
JSON.stringify(appointment);
```

Now from php side, inside the called function I'm trying to get the `id` of the appointment in this way:

```
$_POST['appointment_data']['id'];
```

but I get this error:

> Illegal string offset 'id'

I've also tried with `.id` but the same appear.

NB: if I execute `gettype()` I get string on `$_POST['appointment_data']`
maybe this is the problem? How I can fix this?

**VAR DUMP PRINT**

```
array(2) { ["appointment_data"]=> string(216) "{"id_services":["13","15","14"],"id_users_provider":"86","start_datetime":"2015-11-19 09:45:00","end_datetime":"2015-11-19 10:57:00","notes":"Appuntamento ","is_unavailable":false,"id":"131","id_users_customer":"87"}" ["customer_data"]=> string(146) "{"first_name":"Mario","last_name":"Rossi","email":"mrossi@net.it","phone_number":"0000","address":"","city":"","zip_code":"","notes":"","id":"87"}" }
```

Comment: Try to do `$_POST['appointment_data']->id;` (Doubt it'll work, but it's worth a shot!)

Comment: Don't you need to parse/decode it?

Comment: with sam hint I get: Message: Trying to get property of non-object
I should parse it?

Comment: just `var_dump($_POST)`. See if your data is there

Comment: Yeah, the with var_dump is printed all the content passed as print_r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP isn't going to automatically convert your JSON string into an object.  The combination of the HTTP POST and PHP just isn't that intuitive, and probably shouldn't try to be.  Your biggest clue to the issue is your statement here:

> if I execute `gettype()` I get string on `$_POST['appointment_data']`

In that case it's a string, and a string doesn't have an `id` index.  If you want to convert that JSON string into an object, PHP provides a way to do that:

```
$myObj = json_decode($_POST['appointment_data']);
```

At that point the value you're looking for should be available:

```
$myObj->{'id'}
```